# Can't compile/assemble MRC and MCR coprocessor instructions on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, gcc, assembly, arm, clang

I don't seem to be able to assemble the MCR and MRC ARMv7 instructions (these are coprocessor access instructions) with iPhone? I have some of these instructions in some inline assembly blocks that work quite nicely with the Code Sourcery gcc toolchain building for a different CortexA8 chip (an OMAP chip), but Apple's assemblers - the Clang assembler and their build of the gnu assembler - throw up errors:

```
{standard input}:41:bad instruction `MRC p15,0,r2,C9,C12,0'
{standard input}:56:bad instruction `MCR p15,0,r0,C9,C12,0'
{standard input}:78:bad instruction `MCR p15,0,r0,C9,C12,1'
{standard input}:96:bad instruction `MCR p15,0,r0,C9,C12,2'
{standard input}:119:bad instruction `MCR p15,0,r2,C9,C12,4'
{standard input}:143:bad instruction `MCR p15,0,r0,C9,C12,5'
{standard input}:165:bad instruction `MCR p15,0,r0,C9,C13,1'
{standard input}:187:bad instruction `MCR p15,0,r0,C9,C13,2'
{standard input}:209:bad instruction `MCR p15,0,r0,C9,C13,0'
{standard input}:228:bad instruction `MRC p15,0,r0,C9,C13,0'
{standard input}:253:bad instruction `MRC p15,0,r0,C9,C13,2'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Out of curiosity what are you doing this for, hope someone can help you though.

Comment: These instructions manipulate the c9 section of the Cortex-A8's coprocessor 15. These are the performance counters - cycle counters, bus counters, cache counters, and other useful little counters for profiling ARMv7 code.

Comment: Random guess: have you tried changing "MRC" to "mrc"?

Comment: Egad! @servn - that worked! Gcc has never had a problem with upper and lower case? Add a response to this question and I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: That's the good news. The bad news is Apple has set the USEREN register to 0, which means that none of these performance counters are available in usermode anyways. Oh well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Originally as a comment on the question)

Random guess: have you tried changing "MRC" to "mrc"?  Apple has a relatively ancient ARM assembler that has trouble with anything written in upper-case.