# Low level cycle counter in iOS devices

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, profiling, cortex-a8

Now that it's clear that [the Cortex-A8 performance counters aren't available on the iPhone/iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542696/cant-compile-assemble-mrc-and-mcr-coprocessor-instructions-on-iphone) (they need to be explicitly enabled for usermode, which Apple hasn't done), is there some other way of getting a reasonable cycle count on iOS devices, for micro-profiling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most fine grain timing available to iOS user code via a public API appears to be using mach_absolute_time(), from mach/mach_time.h, whose output appears to scaled results from one of the ASIC's clock cycle counters.  Call it one extra time just before you start timing to pre-fill the ICACHE with the mach_time library code.  Note that some of Apple's ASICs may shift gears for the app's CPU core clock speed, depending.

Answer (score 1):

I might be completely off, but is `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent` too coarse for you?